# Dynamically add table row to table layout on button click

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-tablelayout, dynamically-generated, tablerow

I am trying to add a new row to a table every time a button is clicked on my android app. Everytime I hit the add row button it crashes and gives me an error on the line that it's trying to add the row to the table. The error is java.lang.NullPointerException (not sure what that means I'm pretty new to android development).

Here's code I have below. Any input helps.

The error occurs on the table.addView(tr, new.......    line(almost the last line).

```
public class addItem extends Activity 
{

    private TableLayout table = null;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_additem);

        table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.maintable);

        Button additembutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.additembutton);
        additembutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                update();
            }
        });

    }

    private void update()
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(addItem.this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView tv = new TextView(addItem.this);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tv.setText("New Entry");
        tr.addView(tv);

        table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


    }}
```

it seems as though every works no problems besides that last line.

logcat report:

```
08-19 06:57:54.002: E/AndroidRuntime(3486): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 08-19 06:57:54.002: E/AndroidRuntime(3486): java.lang.NullPointerException 08-19 06:57:54.002: E/AndroidRuntime(3486): at com.mirafriends.recipeme.addItem.update(addItem.java:47) 08-19 06:57:54.002: E/AndroidRuntime(3486): at com.mirafriends.recipeme.addItem.access$0(addItem.java:37) 08-19 06:57:54.002: E/AndroidRuntime(3486): at com.mirafriends.recipeme.addItem$1.onClick(addItem.java:30) 08-19 06:57:54.002: E/AndroidRuntime(3486): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
```

Comment: Can you post the log report as well?

Comment: i'm assuming you mean the error from logCat?

Comment: NullPointException means, that your variable (in this case "table") has the value "null", in other words it isn't initialized. Please edit your question and show us your layout file "maintable".

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this to dynamically add rows to a table.

Please go through:

```
//----------------Essay name table body------------------------------------------
                essay_title_tr_data = new TableRow(this);
                essay_title_tr_data.setId(10);
                essay_title_tr_data.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey_list_bg);
                essay_title_tr_data.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


                    final TextView essay_title = new TextView(this);
                    essay_title.setId(20);
                    essay_title.setText(Html.fromHtml(parser.getValue(e, KEY_Title)));
                    essay_title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    essay_title.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                    essay_title.setTextSize(10);
                    essay_title_tr_data.addView(essay_title);// add the column to the table row here


                    final TextView essay_description = new TextView(this);
                    essay_description.setId(20);
                    essay_description.setText(Html.fromHtml(parser.getValue(e, KEY_Description)));
                    essay_description.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    essay_description.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                    essay_description.setTextSize(10);
                    essay_title_tr_data.addView(essay_description);// add the column to the table row here
//                  String strSubmissionDate=parser.getValue(e, KEY_DateofFormSubmission);

                    final String url=parser.getValue(e, KEY_PDFUrl);



                    essay_title_table.addView(essay_title_tr_data, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

The layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
     android:padding="3dp">

     <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
         android:background="#FFFFFF">

         <ScrollView
             android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

             <RelativeLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                 <ImageView
                     android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                     android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_get" />

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textView1"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
                     android:text="@string/essay_corner"
                     android:textColor="#000000"
                     android:textSize="16sp" />

                 <HorizontalScrollView
                     android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
                     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

                     <RelativeLayout
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                     <TableLayout
                         android:id="@+id/essay_title_table"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                         android:layout_centerVertical="true" >


                     </TableLayout>

                 </RelativeLayout>
                 </HorizontalScrollView>

             </RelativeLayout>

         </ScrollView>

     </RelativeLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

I hope you will get some idea.

Comment: okay thanks. quick question about my code though, is it okay that my main table is not included within my additem activity xml file?

Comment: No, that is not at all ok. You will require the table inside the activity.